# Configurable retry in apache storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using Apache storm to reach messages from kafka and insert data to a database. The messages are corresponding to transactions happened in an Oracle DB. Since we are using storm there is no guarantee on the processing order and some messages which are failure on the first attempt might be success on retry. We need to limit the retry to a threshold value say 10 and beyond this if the failure occurs the messages are moved to an error queue.

To be specific, our requirement is to do retry on bolt execution(on exception) for a specified number of times. After these retries the messages should be moved to Database. We were doing a fieldsGrouping and maintaining a hash map to track the retry count. This was required to make sure that the the retried messages uses the same worker, however this is causing major performance impact. We will have to do shuffleGrouping for maximum throughput. What is the best possible way to implement this behavior. 
The following options are considered.
1)  Maintain the retry count status in database(might be a performance issue).
2)  Maintain the retry count status in external caches( like elasticache in Amazon AWS), however it might be expensive.
3)  Maintain the retry count status in message itself and re-post the message to kafka queue. Also ignoring the exception occurred in bolt to make in success.

We are not considering exponential retry inside bolt itself as it might also cause performance issues.

Please advice.

Comment: I think you'll have to use Trident here to get exactly once and ordered message processing. Also, you might have to extend the default Emitter that comes with the Trident's Kafka Spout to keep track of the Retry Count. On the bolt, keep throwing FailedException / ReportedFailedException until you hit your retry limit post which you can ingest the message to a sideline topic.